# Viewing Collections of Objects in Report

Tags: java, swing, jasper-reports

There is a collection of objects.And I want to show it in a jasper report.Let's say Item class;

```
public class Item{ Color color; Category category;  and getters and setters for color & category}
```

`public class Color{int id; String name; //and getters and setters}
public class Category {int id; String name; // and getters and setter}`
Then the collection has Item objects. I want to show the Color,Category ids and names of  of Items  in jasper report. Please any one tell my how to do this(how to write the expression in jasper report;jrxml).
purchasingList is my collection consist of Item objects.

```
    `try {
        InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Reports/invoice.jasper");
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        JRBeanCollectionDataSource datasource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(purchasingList);

        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(in, params, datasource);
        JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint, true);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to show eg. the category id you have to put something like that in the jrxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0" />
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0" />
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0" />
    <style name="Heading 1" isDefault="false" fontSize="16" isBold="true" />
    <queryString>
                <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="category" class="Category">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[category]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <title>
        <band height="21">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Heading 1"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font isUnderline="true" />
                </textElement>
                <text>Purchases</text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement/>

                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="12" isBold="true" />
                </textElement>
                <text>Category Id</text>
            </staticText>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="23" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <font fontName="Arial" isItalic="true" />
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Integer"><![CDATA[$F{category}.getId()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

You can change the formatting options as needed.

Again, this is an inticative exaple for category id. I thing you can adjust it to the other fields you need, fairly easy.

Comment: com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.errorhandler.ProblemItem@1f5256c java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Entity.ItemName starting from ModuleCL@5ce40[com.jaspersoft.ireport] with possible defining loaders null and declared parents [ModuleCL@15d8d75[org.netbeans.modules.favorites], ModuleCL@9e8c34[org.openide.windows], ModuleCL@f6f1b6[org.netbeans.modules.db], ModuleCL@174a6e2[org.netbeans.api.progress], ModuleCL@1faa614[org.netbeans.modules.languages], ModuleCL@1762fc7[org.openide.loaders], ModuleCL@106df95[org.netbeans.modules.editor.mimelookup],

Comment: org.netbeans.MainImpl$BootClassLoader@17a29a1, ModuleCL@1786a3c[org.openide.dialogs], ModuleCL@17f4fbb[org.netbeans.modules.options.api], ...14 more] com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.outline.nodes.FieldNode@191d0ef[Name=itemName, displayName=itemName]

Comment: ItemName is my class and it is in the package "Entity"

Comment: Here is the jrxml      ` <field name="itemName" class="Entity.ItemName">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[itemName]]>
        </fieldDescription>
    </field>`        and    `  <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{itemName}.getItemName()]]>`

Comment: You have to put your classes (Entity.*) in the classpath while compiling.

Comment: Would you let me know how to do it in Netbeans please.I am new for these things

Comment: I moved my .jrxml file into the package where the ItemName is in. But still the same error comes.

Comment: You have to install the iReport plugin, which by the StackTrace I can see that you 've done. Then go to tools->iReport->classpath and add your *.class or *.jar files.

Comment: Why don't you use the iReport residner and you 're messing around with .jrxml? It's much easier to build a report that way.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that the location of the .jrxml file is irrelevant. Put it where it makes more sense to you.

Comment: I use the netbean 7.0.1 and iReport plugin 4.1.1 :) the iReport >classpath set( first time my jar is set and second time the folder which ItemName class is in set.Each time my application cant be compiled and build. build failed. Then I removed all them. then still can't cllean & build the project. :(

Comment: To the classpath add your <project>/build/classes and make it reloadable. That way any change to the model will be depicted to the report. The report build itself does not conflict with the project's build cyrcle in netbeans. You have to look elsewhere for that problem.

Comment: To compile the .jrxml just press the build button in the designer view (the one on the right of the "preview" button"). If any errors exist you can see them in the "Report Problems Window". If you do have errors in that window, please add them here, so as to have a better understanding of the situation.

Comment: Thank you very much Efthymis ..I did as you mentioned and it worked :) Also once again I should thank you for your guidance and info you gave.I learnt more things apart from my question.